# How do I correctly use mark.js?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make [mark.js](https://markjs.io/) work. I have the following code:

```
<link rel='stylesheet' href='gospel.css'>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="mark.js/mark.js"></script>

<script>
  var context = document.querySelector(".context");
  var instance = new Mark(context);
  instance.mark("Hello" [, options]);
</script>

<div class='context'> Hello there, how are you doing? </div>
```

**gospel.css**

```
/* Mark */

mark{
    background: orange;
    color: black;
}

/* End of Mark */
```

All of the files listed are properly linked and are working. Why isn't mark.js working?

### EDIT

Console Errors: `example.php:8 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ,`

Line 8 is `instance.mark("Hello" [, options]);`

Comment: Have you [checked your console for errors?](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/javascript/185/hello-world/714/using-console-log) You're trying to access an element before it's loaded.

Comment: The error says it all. That's bad syntax. The `[, options]` means you can *optionally* pass some options. If you aren't passing any options, just do `instance.mark("Hello")`. You'll still need to move your script to the end of your code.

Answer (score 1):

use

```
instance.mark("Hello");
```

the [, options] notation tells you that the options parameter is optional.